# How to increase AWS EBS NVME size

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nvme

I have upgraded an EC2 instance from m4 to m5, and now want to increase the size of the attached EBS storage volume. I am using an solid-state (SSD) EBS volume mounted as an NVMe drive.

After some research, I performed this command:

```
growpart /dev/nvme0n1 p1
```

After doing so, I received this error message in response:

```
FAILED: partition-number must be a number
```

I have tried to find instructions in the AWS docs and forums, but have not found a solution to this error message.

How can I increase the size of the EBS volume?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

`growpart [OPTIONS] DISK PARTITION-NUMBER`

```
$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1       259:0    0  16G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128 259:2    0   1M  0 part
```

So to grow the partition, we use the diskname `nvme0n1` (see `disk` under `TYPE`) and desired partition is `1`

```
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
```

And then to extend the fs - 
`resize2fs device [ size ]`

(device refers to the location of the target filesystem)

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                   470M   52K  470M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                      480M     0  480M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1                             7.8G  7.7G  3.1M 100% /
```

So to extend the fs, we use the device name `/dev/nvme01np1`:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Voila!

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                   470M   52K  470M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                      480M     0  480M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1                              16G  7.7G  7.9G  50% /
```

Comment: If I had to increase /dev/nvme0n1p128, then do I have to use "sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 2" ?

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on Ubuntu server 18.04!!

Comment: If you are on FCOS and you can't use any of the native tools than mount the partition as rw then reboot
sudo mount -o remount,rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,prjquota /dev/nvme0n1p4 /sysroot

Comment: Interesting. I followed all of the above (as well as referenced the AWS article you provided). When I issued the "sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1" command I got: NOCHANGE: partition 1 is size 25161695. it cannot be grown

So then I issued the "sudo xfs_growfs -d /" command and got: data size unchanged, skipping -- I read somewhere that after you reboot (after modifying the volume) that AWS expands it for you but I couldn't find that article, so I went through all these steps. Looks like it does do it for you.

Comment: resize2fs didn't work for me. My type was xfs which was solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305376/resize2fs-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-while-trying-to-open

Answer (score 23):

`resize2fs` didn't work for me, so I used this instead:

```
xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

`resize2fs` gave me this error when I used it:

```
[root@ip-1-2-3-4 ~]# resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I noticed the disk was using `xfs` under `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=4cbf4a19-1fba-4027-bf92-xxxxxxxxxxxx     /           xfs    defaults,noatime  1   1
```

Comment: The latest amazon-linux-2 ami on Ec2 uses XFS as the root partition.

Which is why it worked for me, after the regular resize2fs failed me with bad blocksize magic type.

Comment: @Thanks, for the help.. I was facing the exact same issue.. all hail to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Prerequesities:

1. You found the partition you want to extend and there is just one partition on this particular NVME: `/dev/nvme0n1p1` but not `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. Note the mount location: `/`

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/nvme0n1p1 _________ ________  ________  99% /
```

2. You run `lsblk` and it confirms a single partition under the volume `nvme0n1`

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:2    0   400G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0   400G  0 part /
```

Than you first extend your volume through AWS console and then run next code block.

**Single place script**:

```
# /dev/nvme0n1 - volume name, 1 - partition index
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1 
# block for xfs
# / - mount from above. Command will safely fail for non xfs
sudo xfs_growfs -d / 
# block for ext4
# /dev/nvme0n1p1 - partition you would like to extend
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Assembled from this resource: [Extend a Linux file system after resizing a volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console)

Answer (score 1):

**Below worked for me in AWS CENTOS  - Amazon Linux 2 AMIS( Karoo)**

**Step 1 :** Update the EBS volume from AWS console of attached EC2

**Step 2 :** Login( SSH ) to EC2 instance in which the volume is attached

**Step 3 :**  Follow the below commands and just replace the disk name. i.e xda or nvme0n1

**Commands :**

`lsblk`

`sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1`

`df -h`

`sudo xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p1`

**Note :** *You have to use xfs_growfs  instead of resize2fs*

Answer (score 0):

To extend the XFS filesystem, instead of `xfs_growfs` after the `growpart` command I ran:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/nvme0n1p2
sudo lvextend -L +40G -r /dev/mapper/centos_sstemplate-root
```

and it worked.