# Is it "growpart" or "resize2fs" for these new c5 instanced?

Tags: amazon-ec2

$ sudo lsblk

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    4G  0 loop /var/tmp
nvme0n1     259:0    0  500G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    1M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  300G  0 part /
```

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1p2

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p2: 322.1 GB, 322120433152 bytes, 629141471 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please update your question. Here are some helpful hints: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This seems to answer the question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508038/how-to-increase-aws-ebs-nvme-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508038/how-to-increase-aws-ebs-nvme-size)