# How to Increase Disk Space GitLab Runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, cicd

I have GitLab runner running on AWS and I've connected it to my GitLab Project. During on CI/CD Pipeline I want to run End to End test on my React Native mobile using `reactnativecommunity/react-native-android` image. But when want to create SDK the job fail and display error `No space left on device`. However when I run `df -h` on `.gitlab-ci.yml` script display disk overlay only 16G. On GitLab Runner config i use `amazonec2-instance-type=c5d.large` who has 50GB storage disk. My question is how to increase the storage space disk on GitLab runner pipeline more than 16G. Here the output on running `df -h`:

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| overlay | 16G | 14G | 2.2G | 86% | / |
| tmpfs | 64M | 0 | 64M | 0% | /dev |
| tmpfs | 1.9G | 0 | 1.9G | 0% | /sys/fs/cgroup |
| /dev/nvme0n1p1 | 16G | 14G | 2.2G | 86% | /builds |
| shm | 64M | 0 | 64M | 0% | /dev/shm |

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Documentation has it documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html#extend-file-system-nvme)

This question was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563443/1794802)

Comment: on AWS EC2 Instance Type c5d.large not using EBS but on description said `50 NVMe SSD`